# Counter example for uniqueness in Poisson equation with Robin Boundary conditions.

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, examples-counterexamples, boundary-value-problem, poissons-equation

My question is related to the following.

[Prove the uniqueness of poisson equation with robin boundary condition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1607571/prove-the-uniqueness-of-poisson-equation-with-robin-boundary-condition)

I was thinking about the use of $a$ being positive. So I tried to find an example that fails the uniqueness when $a$ is a negative constant. The easiest one might be something working on one dimentional, let us say $\Omega$ is a bounded open interval. For simplicity I took $(0,1)$ and tried some $u_1, u_2$ linear/quadratic different to each other but no success. Can somebody give an idea of how to find such example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $\Omega = (0,\ell)$ for simplicity.  Then $\Delta u = u'' =0$ requires that $u(x) = cx + d$ for $c,d \in \mathbb{R}$.  Plugging into the boundary conditions $\partial_n u -a u =0$ for $a >0$ yields
$$
c - a(c\ell+d) =0 \text{ and } -c-ad =0.
$$
This is equivalent to the linear system
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1-a\ell & -a \\
-1 & -a
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
c \\ d
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\0 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
We have a nontrivial solution if and only if the determinant of the matrix vanishes, which is equivalent to
$$
(1-a\ell)(-a) -a =0 \Leftrightarrow a(a\ell-2) =0
$$
and so we have a degenerate matrix if and only if $a = 2/\ell$.

As long as $a$ and $\ell$ are related in this way we will not have unique solutions to the problem
$$
\begin{cases}
u''(x) = h(x) & \text{for }x \in (0,\ell) \\
\partial_n u - au  =g & \text{for }x=0,\ell. 
\end{cases}
$$