# Uniqueness of PDE solution subjected to mix-boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The Laplace's equation:
$$
\nabla^2\phi=0
$$
subjected to only Neumann's boundary conditions has an infinite number of solution. For a unique solution to exist, we need to have Dirichlet's condition at least at a point on the boundary.

**Question:** If the Laplace's equation is subjected to *purely* mixed-boundary condition:
$$
\alpha(x,y,z)\phi+\beta(x,y,z)\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial n}
=f(x,y,z); \alpha \neq0, \beta\neq0$$
, does a unique solution exist?

Comment: Relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1607571/221811 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2122410/221811

Comment: @Chappers If the solution is unique up to a constant, then does it mean we still need to have a Dirichlet condition at some point on the boundary to have a unique solution?

Comment: The linked question was for a positive constant. Hence, the solution is unique up to a constant if $\frac{\beta}{\alpha} > 0$ everywhere on the boundary.